# How do I add the sum of three bootstrap input sliders automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application where I am trying to add the sum of three bootstrap sliders:

```
<div id="evalOne" class="qrow">
    <div id="q1" class="question q_space">
        <p>Question 1:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="a1" class="question a_right">
        <input id="question1" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
        <span class="CurrentSliderValLabel"><span id="question1Val" class="questionVal">0</span></span>
     </div>         
</div>
<div id="evalTwo" class="qrowa">
    ...         
</div>
<div id="evalThree" class="qrow">
    ...         
</div>

<div id="FinalAnswer" class="qrow">
    ...                
    <span class="CurrentSliderValLabel">Total:<span id="myTotal" class="answerVal">0</span></span>
```

...

Here is what I have tried:
**See Edit**

**Edited Portion**

I wanted to show the reason I was using the span as value. according to [example 6 in the documentation](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) span does have a value

```
$("#question1").slider({step:1, min:0, max:3});
    $("#question1").on('slide', function (slideEvt1) {
    $("#question1Val").text(slideEvt1.value);
});
```

Looking further at the documentation I wondered what would happen if I add the sum to the actual slide event

```
$("#question1").on('slide', function (slideEvt1) {
        $("#question1Val").text(slideEvt1.value);
        $("#myTotal").text(sum = parseInt(slideEvt1.value));
    });

    $("#question2").slider({ step: 1, min: 0, max: 3 });
    $("#question2").on('slide', function (slideEvt2) {
        $("#question2Val").text(slideEvt2.value);
        $("#myTotal").text(sum += parseInt(slideEvt2.value));
    });
```

This changes the span answer total but instead of counting by 3's it counts exponentially unless I remove the `+` from the `sum+=`. However if I remove the `+` the next slider will not total onto the count, instead, the count will start over.

Comment: put the event handler on the inputs, not the span, and use change instead of mouseup/mousedown

Comment: also, the use of `this` is out of scope in your calulate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is out of scope.. do something like this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //this should calculate values automatically 
        // calculateSum(); <-- remove that

        $(".questionVal").on("change", function () {
            calculateSum(this);
        });
    });

    function calculateSum(obj) {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".questionVal").each(function () {
            sum += parseInt(obj.value);
        });

        $("span#myTotal").val(sum.toFixed(0));
    }
```

and then move the `questionVal` class to the input, becuse a span element doesn't have a value attribute..

---

this works..
http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1048/

```
<span class="questionVal">0</span><span class='res'>0</span><br>
<span class="questionVal">0</span><span class='res'>0</span><br>
<span class="questionVal">0</span><span class='res'>0</span><br>
<span class="questionVal">0</span><span class='res'>0</span><br>
<span class='total'>0</span>


$('.questionVal').slider();
$('.questionVal').on("slide", function(e){
    $(this).next().text(e.value);
  var totes = 0;
  $(".res").each(function(){
    totes += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $(".total").text(totes);
});
```

Comment: I will look at and try your suggestion. Please check out my post edits. That is the reason why I thought to use the span

Comment: @Skullomania - if you look close, that's the event object that's got a value, not the span :)

Comment: I did try your suggestion please look at the edit I made

Comment: you won't be able to use the event method like in example 6 becuase there's only going to be an event for the one that was changed and you're trying to get the value of all of them, you see? try what i gave you and maybe give me some credit if you want me to keep helping you.

Comment: I have given you credit for trying to help, however the reason why I have not marked it as an answer is because the solution you provided does not work. The total does not change, it remains as zero, however, it does not show any errors in the console. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The edit that I made however does cause the total to add - and subtract just not when I try to combine them

Comment: thanks, i might not have solved the problem yet, but i did point out some errors in your code, which probably deserves a thumbs up :P i'll make you a quick fiddle..

Comment: No need. I have found my own solution and will post it shortly. Thanks!